# HTML Centered Title with Image Left Aligned

Tags: html, css, formatting

How can I get an image aligned to the left corner of the page with a centered title?

**What I tried:**

```
<div style="display: flex; height: 100px;">
    <img style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;" src="static/totally_original_logo.jpg" alt="totally original logo">
    <div style="text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">
        <a href="foo.com">Return to home</a>
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: screenshot]

---

```
<div style="display: flex; height: 100px; justify-content: center;">
    <img style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;" src="static/totally_original_logo.jpg" alt="totally original logo">
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="foo.com">Return to home</a>
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

**What I want:**
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Keep `justify-content: center` on the div tag and give the img a `justify-self: start` property. You may need to give the div a width of 100% as well.

```
img {
justify-self: start;
}
div {
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, however adding these did not get me the desired output. It ends up looking like the first picture. I didn't downvote your answer, I'm guessing it's the same person that marked my Question as a duplicate. The other post has an excellent answer using columns or hidden elements to achieve what I wanted. Thanks for responding though!